# How to hide "Preferences" item in Mac application menu

Tags: java, macos, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an application built atop the Eclipse rich-client platform. It does not yet have any user preferences.

Currently on the Mac, the "Preferences" menu item in the application menu is enabled, but does nothing.

Is there an easy way to hide or disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into the same problem, I chose a simple solution to the root problem -- show the Preferences dialog.

Even in the absence of application-layer user preferences, there were still preferences panels contributed by the help plug-ins.

With the current implementation of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.carbon.CarbonUIEnhancer,` the application-menu "Preferences" item requires and executes a preferences menu item elsewhere in the menus (e.g., ActionFactory.PREFERENCES).